# Jquery Mobile Loading Icon on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

As usual, I'm struggling with jquery mobile...

I've a form :

```
<form data-role="none" action='cart_checkout.php' METHOD='POST' data-ajax="false">
  <input type="hidden" name="itemname" value="test" />
  <input type="hidden" name="itemdesc" value="test" />
  <input type="hidden" name="itemnumber" value="f1" />
  <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="teste" />
  <input type="hidden" name="itemprice" value="99.00" />
  <input type="hidden" name="itemQty" value="1" />
  <input type="hidden" name="useraction" value="commit" />
  <input data-role="none" onclick="$.mobile.showLoadingMsg();" type="image" name="submit" src="images/checkout.png" border="0" align="top" alt="Check out with PayPal"/>
</form>
```

I would like to show the Loading Icon when the user clicks on submit.
I've tried many examples but the loading icon isn't displayed.

My header looks like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

What's wrong here ?

Comment: you missed the `/` from `custom` and `useraction` inputs

Comment: @jcho360 tks but still not working.

Comment: why don't you use just a hide-display image with regular jquery?

Comment: you're using old version of jQM. I dont know if this works for jQM 1.1, but it works for 1.2 `$.mobile.showLoadingMsg()` `$.mobile.hideLoadingMsg()`. The one you're using now `$.mobile.loading("show/hide")` is to be used with jQM and higher.

Comment: I've changed the version but it doesn't work with `jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.js` also

Comment: this isn't correct `onclick="$.mobile.showLoadingMsg();"`, `$("#form_ID").on("submit", function () { $.mobile.showLoadingMsg(); });`

Comment: I just noticed that `data-ajax=false` is added to form. Loading msg wont appear in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I've solve my problem with this:

```
<form data-role="none" action='cart_checkout.php' METHOD='POST' data-ajax="false">
<input type="hidden" name="itemname" value="test" />
<input type="hidden" name="itemdesc" value="test" />
<input type="hidden" name="itemnumber" value="f1" />
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="teste" />
<input type="hidden" name="itemprice" value="99.00" />
<input type="hidden" name="itemQty" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="useraction" value="commit" />
<input data-role="none" id="go" onclick="$('#loading').show(); $('#go').hide()" type="image" name="submit" src="images/checkout.png" border="0" align="top" alt="Check out with PayPal"/>
</form>
<div id="loading" style="display:none;">
<p align=center"> Redirecting </p>
<img src="loading.gif" alt="" /></div>
```